# retrieving row based on input

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

```
public void RemoveTask(int index) {
  SQL = "DELETE FROM Task where (...) = " +index;

  dbConn.Open();

  dbCommand = new SqlCeCommand(SQL, dbConn);
  dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

  dbConn.Close();
}
```

What i want to do is to delete the record based on the index which specified the row number but I don't know what function or variable should be used ( note the blank ), i try something like rowNum but it does not work.

any help will be appreaciated

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Do you know about table structure you are doing with? If all you want to do is delete a value from a table based on a row's primary key then this is very simple. Just Delete From Task Where TaskId = index. TaskId is just the column name. Note that you should also be using parameters in your sql as a general best practice.

Comment: I have a table called task but there is not TaskId as I am not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Good point @OMG ponies - I just answered figuring it was Sql Server, assuming if from the tags and the SqlCeCommand.

Comment: @christine You will need to know the name of the column where that index value came from. Without knowing that sort of information, what you are trying to do is not possible (well, it might be on a DB that I'm not familiar with)

Comment: So - you want to let users delete rows from the database based on the position of that row in the database? That doesn't really make sense. DB implementation details like the position of rows are meaningless to users. Introduce a primary key that is an identity column then every time you get values from the db, hold onto that value along with your records. Then use the identity for the deleterd record to do you deletion.

Comment: I tried using identity before but again "DBCC CHECKIDENT" which let me reset the value ( so that it does not start where it left ) does not seems to be recognised. I need the row to be sequential.

Comment: Why does it need to be sequential? These values should never be displayed to users. Do you have a business requirement that you need to have a sequential number assigned to each record that does not ever contain gaps?

Comment: yep, because when I delete the tasks, it is based on the index , in this case my index will always be sequential, so i need to somehow reset my ID( assumed identity column) , everytime I deleted one row, the next row should have ID of the previous row so that my ID will always be sequential.

Comment: But why does the delete need to be based on the index? Why can't you use the id? Here is a post that talks about reseeding the identity of a table http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-server-%E2%80%93-reseed-identity-of-table-%E2%80%93-table-missing-identity-values-%E2%80%93-gap-in-identity-column/

Comment: I guess doing that is a bit too hard, esp when 'DBCC CHECKIDENT' is not recognised, anyway, I just use other ways. So the reason I used index is because I have a an GUI with list menu in it, so the index is from selected item in list menu which has data from my tables. Anyway,thanks for the help

Comment: But why can't you bind your list to a collection of objects that contain your db ids? That is the standard way of doing this and should meet your needs. If you aren't quite sure how to do that, post a question on binding a list to a collection of obejcts, and mention that you want to get the unique id for the selected object.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do. I think the following code is what you are after - it deletes a row based on the primary key where in this case the name of the primary key column is TaskId (but you can change that based on your table column names).

Note that it also uses parameterised SQL which gives better performance and security.

```
SQL = "DELETE FROM Task where TaskId = @taskid"; 

dbConn.Open(); 

dbCommand = new SqlCeCommand(SQL, dbConn); 

dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@taskid", SqlDbType.Int);
dbCommand.Parameters["@taskid"].Value = index;

dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

dbConn.Close();
```

Comment: emm, TaskId will then contain row number ie 1,2,3,4 depending on how many columns we have, but how do I create TaskId , I tried using identity but then I need to reset the seed each time I delete one record but the 'DBCC CHECKIDENT' does not seems to work as well

Comment: Oww, I am using sql server compact